# Where can I find a JSX and HTML syntax reference table?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new in reactjs.

In jsx, some syntax is different from HTML

for example

```
html        jsx  
class -- > className
onkeypress --> onKeyPress
onclick --> onClick
```

I want to know where can I find the comparable (reference) table to know which word to use?

Thank you!

Comment: That's about it. I suggest the react docs.

Answer (score 0):

`for -> htmlFor and class --> className` are the only special reserved javascript-to-HTML names I am aware of.

Other special event names can be found here:
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#supported-events